# URL rewrite with PHP & MySQL and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I have my site as `localhost/tutorials/rewrite/news.php` on this page are titles from news articles that are in my database. Each title is a link to read the article. The link is

```
'<a href="read-news.php?url=' . $url . '">' . $title1. '</a>'
```

The read-news.php page gets the url and uses it in an sql statement to get the article from the database

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE url = '$url'";
```

My link on the news.php page and the url on the read-news.php looks like this

```
localhost/tutorials/rewrite/read-news.php?url=the-news-today
```

How can i get it to look like

```
localhost/tutorials/rewrite/read-news/the-news-today.php
```

I have used the following htaccess code which by looking at other examples i thought should be enough to fix it

```
RewriteRule ^read-news/(.*).php /read-news.php?url=$1 [PT]
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: your RewriteRule needs some work too. try this:

`RewriteRule ^read-news/(.*)\.php$ /read-news.php?url=$1 [PT]`

(you need to use a "$" to signal the end of your rewrite and escape the . before "php" with a backslash)

Also, you should link to your pages how you want them displayed:

`href="localhost/tutorials/rewrite/read-news/the-news-today.php"`

The .htaccess won't magically change the urls for you.

Also if you want to be able to access your query string variables, i would add QSA to your flags: `[PT,QSA]`

that way you can still access your url variable with `$_GET['url']`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it how Wordpress does it. Rewrite everything into index.php and parse the url from script.

Comment: how is that done? are there any tutorials on how to do it easily?

Comment: I'm not sure on tutorials but it surely is easy. `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` this rule sends all traffic to **index.php**. In index.php you can have `$path = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` and for `http://localhost/tutorials/rewrite/read-news` $path[0] would be 'tutorials', $path[1] would be 'rewrite', etc. Does this make sense?